# Oracle - add column in unpivot query which does not exist in the table

Tags: sql, oracle, unpivot

In table I have column ID, CAR_1,CAR_2,CAR_3...

```
SELECT 1 as ID, 100 as CAR_1, 200 as CAR_2, 300 as CAR_3 from dual;
```

How get CAR_DAY column eg. for CAR_1 = 1, CAR_2 = 2 etc..

How get this:

| ID | CAR_ID | CAR_DAY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 1 |
| 1 | 200 | 2 |
| 1 | 300 | 3 |

My demo but not working:

```
SELECT
  ID,
  CAR_ID,
  CAR_DAY,
FROM
  CARS
UNPIVOT
(
  (CAR_ID, CAR_DAY) FOR COL IN
  ((CAR_1, 1),  (CAR_2, 2), (CAR_3, 3))
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here how to do it using `unpivot` :

```
SELECT ID, CAR_ID, REPLACE(CAR_DAY, 'CAR_', '') AS CAR_DAY 
FROM (
   SELECT 1 as ID, 100 as CAR_1, 200 as CAR_2, 300 as CAR_3
   FROM dual
)
UNPIVOT
( CAR_ID FOR CAR_DAY IN (CAR_1, CAR_2, CAR_3) );
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/9bKngj51)

Comment: Tnx for help, but value 100,200,300 not show in resault

Comment: My mistake, I fixed it, can you check

Answer (score 1):

Use `AS` in the `UNPIVOT` list:

```sql
SELECT ID,
       CAR_ID,
       CAR_DAY
FROM   CARS
UNPIVOT (
  CAR_ID FOR car_day IN (
    CAR_1 AS 1,
    CAR_2 AS 2,
    CAR_3 AS 3
  )
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE cars (id, car_1, car_2, car_3) AS
SELECT 1, 100, 200, 300 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ID | CAR_ID | CAR_DAY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 1 |
| 1 | 200 | 2 |
| 1 | 300 | 3 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/8n5gBGvV)